# How to handle changes in Venue Map used for events

Tags: mysql

I have events using different venues for seating.

They are saved in 3 different tables.

```
Venues (has information about the venue like name, location, capacity etc)
id  | name  | location | capacity 

Venue_chart (has information about seating chart with rows and column)
id  | venue_id | seat_type | row  | column  | label

seat_type
id  | name  | css_color | description
```

Now when an event is created as of now I save those data into a table with one to one relation with events table

```
event_venues
id | event_id | venue_id | some extra columns
```

This works fine when an event wants to change the venue completely if the venue is not available or last minute change, I only delete entry in `event_venues` row and insert 1 new row.

The issue is on the `venues` table side. How do I handle changes in the venue seating map? How do I make sure that the changes in venue seating map will only apply to new events and not affect existing or past events.

In short if I make change in venue seating map today then, all new events using the venue will see changes but the existing and old one should see the old seating map?

I thought of creating a new table called `event_venue_chart` and copy all rows (which could be 300 per venue) from `venue_chart` table. That way any new changes will not affect existing or old events. I realised that it will create many duplicate rows will only change in `eventId`.

Thank you

Comment: So you need a table which records which event belongs to which venue_seating_map. Presumably, an event can only belong to one vsm, so it seems logical to store this in the events table

Comment: No I need to handle the changes in `venue_chart` table, if a venue seating is changed, should I create a completely new map or just change a few rows in `venu_chart` table? If I change few rows in `venue_chart` table, it should only effect new events and not existing events that are using `venue_chart`

Comment: Because changes cannot apply retrospectively, I would create a new map

Comment: Yes ok, As of now I am doing that but sometimes the change is just one row or change of seat name etc. Sometimes I have to add 300 rows for a small change in one section of map.

Comment: Well if it made sense to divide maps up into sections then a vsm could simply be comprised of sections, so you'd only need to store smaller amounts in the event of any change. But that said, 300 rows is a tiny number, and of no consequence to a modern RDBMS